# Eslint: Manually control absolute and relative imports

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tslint, javascript-import

I'd like to have a eslint rule which will make to have relative import paths for everything that is imported from inside of the directory and absolute paths for everything that is imported from outside of the directory.

Example: This is my file structure

```
/Dashboard
    /components
        /Component1.tsx
/Home
    /components
        /Component2.tsx
        /Component3.tsx
    /utils
        /util1.ts
style.ts
```

I want to have relative imports inside of my **Home** directory and absolute imports for everything that imported from outside of my **Home** directory.

My Component2.tsx's imports should look like this

```
import Component3 from './Component3'
import util1 from './../util1'
import FlexBox from './../../styled'
import Component1 from 'Dashboard/components/component1' // this should be absolute
```

Answer (score 0):

Could something like this work?

To enforce relative imports only for within the Home directory, you could configure the rule [`no-restricted-imports`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports) to disallow imports starting with "Home".

Add this rule to the ESLint configuration file:

```json
{
  rules: {
    "no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "patterns": ["Home/*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This will give an error if the module name to import from starts with "Home".

In `Component2.tsx`:

```js
import Component3 from 'Home/components/Component3' //error
import util1 from 'Home/utils/util1' //error
import FlexBox from 'Home/abc/xyz/styled' //error
import Component1 from 'Dashboard/components/component1' //no error
```

If you want to do the same for the Dashboard directory as well, you would need to use a separate configuration for each directory instead. You can do this with the `overrides` key in the ESLint configuration file:

```json
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["Home/*"],
      rules: {
        "no-restricted-imports": [
          "error",
          {
            "patterns": ["Home/*"]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["Dashboard/*"],
      rules: {
        "no-restricted-imports": [
          "error",
          {
            "patterns": ["Dashboard/*"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Akasha, thanks for your answer but it's not what I'm exactly looking for. I'd like to allow relative paths inside of the page, but have an absolute path if anything is imported from another page. I wasn't able to find any rule for that so I end up writing my own custom rule

Comment: Hi Vahan, This https://github.com/msfragala/eslint-plugin-path-alias rule may be similar to your requirement except that it will be the opposite. 

Could you share your rule? 
I need a similar requirement needed to use a relative path for the sibling files.